# Automatically determine whether a form filled in by hand and then scanned is valid

Tags: machine-learning, conv-neural-network, image-processing, optical-character-recognition

I'd like to automatically determine whether a form which is filled in by hand and then scanned or photographed is "valid".

To be considered valid, the form has to satisfy the following two criteria:

1. Two given checkboxes have been checked.
2. There is a signature.

One approach to solve this would be to use an optical image recognition tool to count the number of pixels in the given locations. If the pixel counts are high enough, the form is then classified as valid.

However, this approach may be vulnerable to the scan/image being

- rotated or shifted (the OCR tool is looking in the wrong place)
- of poor quality (the OCR tool wrongly considers background pixels as filled or filled pixels as background)

Another approach that may work is training an image recognition tool such as TensorFlow's.

My programming language of choice is Python, but I can use others if necessary.

How can I go about solving this problem?

Comment: The question is too broad.

Comment: Sounds like an expert computer vision problem? Do you have *tons* of data classified as valid or invalid so you can test the accuracy of various algorithms?

Comment: @MatthewGunn I could get data, but I'm unsure of how much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution using [Clarifai](https://clarifai.com/):

```
from clarifai.rest import ClarifaiApp
from clarifai.rest import Image
from clarifai.rest import client
import os
```

app = ClarifaiApp(os.environ['CLARIFAI_APP_ID'], os.environ['CLARIFAI_APP_SECRET'])

try:
    trained_model = app.models.get('form')
except client.ApiError:
    path_to_training_images = 'images/training/'
    path_to_valid_images = path_to_training_images + 'valid/'
    path_to_invalid_images = '%sinvalid/' % path_to_training_images
    valid_image_filenames = os.listdir(path_to_valid_images)

```
training_images = [
    Image(
        filename=path_to_invalid_images + 'invalid.png',
        concepts=['invalid'],
        not_concepts=['valid']
    )
]

for valid_image_filename in valid_image_filenames:
    path_to_valid_image = path_to_valid_images + valid_image_filename
    valid_image = Image(
        filename=path_to_valid_image,
        concepts=['valid'],
        not_concepts=['invalid'],
    )

    training_images.append(valid_image)

app.inputs.bulk_create_images(training_images)

model = app.models.create(
    model_id='form',
    concepts=['valid', 'invalid'],
    concepts_mutually_exclusive=True,
)
model.train()

trained_model = app.models.get('form')
```

prediction = trained_model.predict_by_filename('images/testing/valid9.png')

most_likely_concept = prediction['outputs'][0]['data']['concepts'][0]

print(
    'The form is %.2f percent likely to be %s.' % (
        most_likely_concept['value'] * 100,
        most_likely_concept['name'],
    )
)

For full code sample (including images), see the repository [yhoiseth/predict-form-validity](https://github.com/yhoiseth/predict-form-validity).